# Show supremum norm of solution to ode is less than $k$ i.e. $||e^{At}|| \leq k$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jordan-normal-form, cauchy-problem

So I'm trying to make an exercise in ode's.

Let $A \in M_5(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix with 3 eigen-values $\lambda_1 = -1$ with multiplicity $3$ and $\dim(\text{Ker}(A+I))=1$, $\lambda_{2,3} = \pm 2i$. Let $J$ be the Jordan form of the matrix $A$.

Now the exercise asks to write down $J$, I simply get,
$$
J_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0\\\\
0 & -1 & 1\\\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
J_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
+2i\\\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
J_3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
-2i\\\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
J =
\begin{pmatrix}
J_1 & 0 & 0\\\\
0 & J_2 & 0\\\\
0 & 0 & J_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm curious if this is correct.
After that the exercise asks to prove that the supremum norm on $||e^{Jt}||\leq 1 \quad \forall t \geq 0$. With this fact the problem stated in the title is easily solved. I know that for the Jordan matrix we have
$$
e^{Jt} =
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{J_1 t} & 0 & 0\\\\
0 & e^{J_2 t} & 0\\\\
0 & 0 & e^{J_3 t}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now if we verify for the different blocks it seems to work for every block except the $e^{J_2 t}$ block as is simply a scalar value equal to $e^{\lambda_2 t} = e^{2 i t}$ for which the norm obviously is greater than one for all $t \geq 0$. I don't think the exercise is wrong but that I'm missing something here, maybe I should use the $\dim(\text{Ker}(A+I))=1$ property as I haven't really used it?

After that the exercise asks to express the solution to a generic cauchy problem with the linear operator $A$ as a function of $J, t_0, x_0$ and ofcourse the transormation matrix to get the Jordan form.

Anyway if someone could help me here, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: 1) You used that condition when you wrote the explicit form of $J_1$. 2) why do you think that the norm of $e^{2it}$ is (obviously) greater than one?

Comment: $||e^{2it}|| = ||\cos(t) + i*\sin(t)||^2 = \sqrt(\cos^2(t) - \sin^2(t))^2 \leq \cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t) \leq 1$. Wow.... I'm sorry

Comment: Don't worry, but for real $\theta$, $|e^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}} =\sqrt{1}=1$.